# Is there any browser which support page-break right?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to use `page-break-before: right` on css, but it only half work. I mean it insert a page break, but doesn't add a blank page when needed (so that the page number is always even : that's how I understand `right`).

I tried Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera. All start a new page, but none of them insert a blank page.
Also when I look using Chrome or Opera the computed style it seems transformed to always. I got

```
page-break-before: always;
       .picking-list: right -- picking.css
```

Am I doing something wrong , or is there a workaround (use another browser, javascript , etc ...)?

Comment: @DavinTryon it's not a duplicate. My question is about `right` and `left`. Moreover, the answers might be outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Always insert a page break before each  element (when printing):

```
    @media print {  h1 {page-break-before: always;} }
```

Please your visit this web site : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp